# How to use contains and like in one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains, sql-like

I wish to use 'contains' and 'like' in one sql server query like this:

```
select *
from product
where 
contains(product.title, '"*grand theft auto 5 (inkl. A*"')
or product.title like 'grand theft auto 5 (inkl. A%'
```

but it seems that this is not working together, no error but sql server will not ending the request.

this works:

```
select *
from product
where 
contains(product.title, '"*grand theft auto 5 (inkl. A*"')
```

this works also

```
select *
from product
where 
product.title like 'grand theft auto 5 (inkl. A%'
```

My idea combining this is that i cannot find the product because of the '. A'

I think '.' is a stop word but if i can combine it with like that will solve by problem.

Any help?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `contains` with `freetext` and get rid of double quotes and stars in search string:

```
select *
from product
where freetext(product.title, 'grand theft auto 5 (inkl. A')
```

Comment: this will return a lot of results containing one of the words. it should get the exact string contains

Comment: Ok. You may leave `contains` but remove noise-words from search string and divide it on separate words: `where contains(product.title, '"grand" & "theft" & "auto" & "5" & "inkl"')`. And only after that slice result set with `like`.